# Find Code Issues misses obvious error?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I was wondering, how come resharper's code analysis tool cannot find the obvious null reference exception here?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass()
        {
            TestCollection.Add(new object());
        }

        public Collection<object> TestCollection
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

I understand the property could initialize itself, but it definitely doesn't here. Can it detect this? It is also not part of a base class that instantiated it.

The following does give a .NET compile warning which code issues lists:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public TestClass()
        {
            TestCollection.Add(new object());
        }

        private Collection<object> TestCollection;
    }
}
```

Is it because any property getter or method call could initialize the collection so they have assumed it was too difficult to determine if it was actually assigned? (but this happens to be a simple case)

Comment: I guess TestClass could be the superclass for another class which defines a new TestCollection? What happens if you change the property to private or the class to sealed?

Comment: Resharper actually warns you if you use a virtual method in a constructor (because that can cause problems). Also, keep in mind, subclassing this class doesn't allow the code to run before the parent class constructor because it is not virtual. If I make it private, it says the 'set' is not used, but doesn't complain about unassigned use. If I make it sealed (but public), no one complains.

Comment: You should really ask JetBrains this question.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I thought they frequent this tag on SO too, but yeah I'll look into something more direct.

Comment: To the person who voted to close as "too broad" What do you mean? It is a straightforward question.

Comment: I couldn't think of a close reason that came closer to "how would _we_ know - go ask the vendor".